# Where could I ask for the best place(s) to share some film's subtitle I made?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know SE isn't usually the best place to ask such (as I think I understood) but still …

I already have found some resources to do that but,
I feel like that performing a search (on Google or what not) doesn't necessarily imply giving me what I was looking for:
The best place to share some subtitles I made.
A place that would be a good, trusted one and widely-use.

It seems that, even if it isn't a rule, top answers in search engine can be there for other reasons such as because they paid for it, so maybe some users know good/better place to perform such a specific task. (Either on a related topic sub SE or on a not existing-yet resource sharing sub SE)

Thank in advance.

Comment: To be clear, you have subtitled a movie (e.g. from German to English), and you're looking for a place to share your results? How exactly would that work, you'd post the entire alternate text to a script or a file for video editing software? I'm really confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: @TimPost The subtitles are in a separated file and most video players have an option to add subtitles to a video that doesn't have any. So it is to be downloaded for people who would be looking for the subtitles of a film in a certain language. (I don't know if it really answers your question) (But maybe some people would have some better ideas, the fact is that I have some subtitles that I'd like to share somehow, the best way if possible)

Comment: Ah, okay, that answers my question perfectly. I was just confused on how you would share the actual work. As for a site? I really don't know. We do have a site for movies, but I don't know if requests for subtitles (a predicate to asking the question which you answer by providing the location of your work) would be on topic there.

Comment: @Siva Thanks for the tip, but I agree it's a bit ambiguous so I don't know either. Do subtitles fit into that definition? I could still ask on their meta.

Comment: [opensubtitles.org](http://www.opensubtitles.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a question it doesn't fit into any of the sites.

It's the same as asking for a webhost, a place to show off your photos or a way to distribute your game mod.

When your question is asking for a place to promote or distribute something it won't fall into any site's scope.

Comment: I think it's a bit playing with words but would there be a SE site where you can ask good place to do something? If so, still from my point of view, I only seek for a good place to share, that's not very that different from another action. I could even, even if it's a bit cheatty, saying that I'm looking for a good place TO FIND what I'm looking for (Then it'll be up to me to use it the way I originally intended it). See what I mean? (I know I'm playing with words a bit) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You could try and "cheat" but that other version would still be off topic. You don't ask for resources, you ask and have resources mentioned as back up to the answer given

Comment: This research suggested me that it was usually accepted but I may be wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+the+best+place+to+find if it is accepted, this is a flaw in this "rule" (maybe it's only something people usually do) of SE sites as something usually 'forbidden'/disapproved can just be asked slightly differently to get you the same, so what's the big deal? But again, I understand your answers, thank you for these.

Comment: It may have worked in the past, but users are coming to the realisation these questions are ill-contained

Comment: Oh? I didn't notice that those questions were old. That makes more sense. Thank you! It's still sad that such a place doesn't exist, gonna see if anyone is interested in the area 51.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be on topic if someone *asked* for subtitles for that movie in the that language. Then you could give them your work. But there is no place on SE for posting your work. Keep looking around.

Comment: It's not really to post my work, even though I clearly understand your point of view. It is to ask for the best place(s) to post it (so not on SE), so that my work wouldn't be post here at any time (that's not the goal).

Comment: @JeromeJ: Oh! In that case, I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea.